# Cohort query with Elasticsearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I'm trying to analyze a cohort using event data in Elasticsearch and have difficulties finding an efficient query to extract that data.

[image]

Can anyone provide me some sample elasticsearch query or give me some idea how I can achieve this result with elasticsearch?